# Dart Mocking a Stream

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-async

I am trying to test a class that uses WebSockets by mocking the socket

My class looks something like

```dart
class WebLoggerHandler{

   WebLoggerHandler(){

     var webSocket = new WebSocket('hostUrl');
     webSocket.onOpen.first.then((_) {
       webSocket.sendString('hello');
     });
   }
}
```

I am mocking the WebSocket class as follows

```dart
class MockWebSocket extends Mock implements WebSocket{        
  Stream<Event> onOpen;
}
```

The body of my test looks like

```dart
  var webSocket = new MockWebSocket();

  //fire the onOpen event 
  webSocket.onOpen = new Stream.fromFuture( new Future.value( new Event( "onOpen")));

  WebLoggerHandler underTest = new WebLoggerHandler();

  //test that the hello message was sent when the socket was opened
  webSocket.getLogs( callsTo("sendString", 'hello')).verify( happenedExactly(1))
```

But it doesnt work as the onClose event happens after the checking of the webSocket logs has occurred.

How do I make the code wait for the Future to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read the API docs and have worked it out. The test needs to return a future

```
   test("it should send 'hello' to the server", () {

      return new Future.value().then((_) {

        webSocket.getLogs(callsTo("sendString", {'hello'})).verify(happenedExactly(1));

      });

   });
```